# Binding dynamic list of CheckBoxes' IsChecked property

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a situation where I load a list of objects from an SQL database. For each of the objects, I want to display a `CheckBox` in an `ItemsControl` and have its `IsChecked` property bound to `true` if and only if a member of the window's `DataContext` contains that object in a list.

Let's call my window `MyWindow`. The `DataContext` of `MyWindow` is an object of type `MyContext` which has a list of objects (loaded from a database) of type `DataObject`, and an object of type `Item`:

```
public class MyContext {
  public Item CurrentItem { get; set; }

  public List<DataObject> Data { get; set; }
}

public class Item {
  public List<DataObject> CheckedDataObjects { get; set; }
}
```

In `MyWindow.xaml` I have my `ItemsControl` which is bound to the `Data` list. The `ItemTemplate` defines that each `DataObject` should be displayed with a `CheckBox`, which should have its `IsChecked` bound to true if and only if the particular `DataObject` is contained in `MyWindow.DataContext.CurrentItem.CheckedDataObjects`.

My best idea is to use an `IMultiValueConverter` approach, however I get an `XamlParseException` with an inner `InvalidOperationException`, saying that two-way binding requires Path or XPath (loosely translated). Please advise!

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <CheckBox>
        <CheckBox.IsChecked>
          <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyItemHasDataObjectConverter}">
            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MyWindow}}" Path="DataContext.CurrentItem"/>
            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
          </MultiBinding>
        </CheckBox.IsChecked>
      </CheckBox>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>

public class ItemHasDataObjectConverter : IMultiValueConverter {
  public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
    // values should contain two objects: the CurrentItem object and an object of type DataObject
    if (values.Length == 2 && values[0] is Item && values[1] is DataObject) {
      return (values[0] as Item).CheckedDataObjects.Contains(values[1] as DataObject);
    }
    return false;
  }

  public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

### EDIT

After Aabid's answer below, the converter now seems to work correctly. Further, I've added `Checked` and `Unchecked` event handlers to the `CheckBox` objects, which add/remove the corresponding `DataObject` object from `CurrentItem.CheckedDataObjects`. However, if I reset `CurrentItem.CheckedDataObjects` via code behind, either by calling `Clear()` or setting `CheckedDataObjects = new List<DataObject>()`, the `CheckBox` does not get updated in the UI (they stay checked).

I have made sure both `MyContext` and `Item` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and fire the corresponding `OnPropertyChanged` methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the Path=DataContext property to your second Binding in your multivalue binding, i.e

```
 <Binding Path=DataContext RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The converter now seems to get the correct input objects. I also added event handlers for `Checked` and `UnChecked` for the checkboxes, which add/remove the corresponding `DataObject` object to `CurrentItem.CheckedDataObjects`. Actually, the only thing that doesn't seem to work now is if I do `CheckedDataObjects.Clear()` or `CheckedDataObjects = new ...` in code behind, then it doesn't update the checkboxes in the UI (they remain checked). Any ideas here?

Comment: When clearing a list the appropriate collection changed events are not fired to let the UI know to update. Using an observable collection instead of a list will help you in this regard. Also, you have bound the items control to Data and not CheckedDataObjects. Clearing or reassigning that will not cause an update to your Data collection.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I was using an ObservableCollection, but the last part of your comment fixed it!